# Rails 3 user activity history data

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, history

So this one has me a bit confused, and it may be unjustified but I would like some input regardless.

I have a rails 3.1.3 application with users who can view media files.  I want to keep a history of their activities with regards to their media viewing.  The goal is to be able to record a history such that I can track it from the user or from the media e.g. get data for user.history() and media.history() to show both all of the media accessed by a user and all of the users who accessed a particular piece of media, along with other data regarding each transaction.

So far the only way I have been able to come up with that reasonably satisfies this is to create a single history object for each transaction, sort of like this:

```
class history_item
   belongs_to: media_object
   belongs_to: user
   (other transaction-specific data)
end
```

What concerns me about this is the number of database entries will quickly skyrocket with the typical use of this application.  Is there a better way to approach this problem that I have not thought of?  I am new to rails and large web application development in general, and I'm not entirely sure about how this sort of thing is normally done.

Answer (score 0):

I would create such a model as a `Viewing` class as a HABTM model between `User` and `MediaObject`. This makes the actual structure more obvious than just having a relation called `history`. You can of course add methods for `User#history` and `MediaObject#history` as well, if you want that exact interface that you described.

```
class User
  has_many :viewings
  has_many :viewed_media_objects, :through => :viewings
end

class MediaObject
  has_many :viewings
  has_many :viewers, :through => :viewings
end

class Viewing
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :media_object
end
```

When querying these objects, for example given a `user = User.first`, if you know that you want to iterate over the user's `viewed_media_objects` in an action, you could use `@user = User.include(:viewed_media_objects).find(params[:id])` to make sure rails fetches the related viewings and media objects at the same time as the user. This way, you won't get a whole bunch of database calls.